# Logic of selecting date if two months come together

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating makemytrip website where in the task is to select date.
The problem is in the date picker two months come together and i think this has become common in many websites.
I want to select date as 2nd September 2021 but the problem is it clicking on months beyond September 2021
.
Below is my logic

1. Get first Month text which is shown in calendar popup.
2. Get second Month text which is shown in calendar popup.
3. Compare (1) and (2) with the month we want
4. Get all the dates

Below is the code and screenshot of website.

```
By datepicker=By.xpath("//div[@class='fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget ']/label");
    waitforelement(15,datepicker);
    driver.findElement(datepicker).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    List<WebElement> dates=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@aria-disabled='false']//div"));
    String first_month_year=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']//div)[1]")).getText();
    System.out.println(first_month_year);
    String second_month_year=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']//div)[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println(second_month_year);
    String first_month=first_month_year.split("")[0].trim();
    String second_month=second_month_year.split("")[0].trim();
    String first_year=first_month_year.split("")[1].trim();
    String second_year=second_month_year.split("")[1].trim();
    while(!(first_month.equals("September")&& first_year.equals("2021")) || (second_month.equals("September") && second_year.equals("2021")))
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='DayPicker-NavButton DayPicker-NavButton--next']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        List<WebElement> dates1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@aria-disabled='false']//div"));
        for(int i=0;i< dates.size();i++)
        {

            String date=dates1.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(date);

        }
```

Please help me to correct the logic so that i can select the date.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you asking it again? I see it is already answered. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544732/how-to-select-date-from-makemytrip-having-two-months-in-popup/68545656)

Comment: Just wanted to ask this too :)
Also, what is the exact link to that page?

Comment: Its a different question.This question is more on logic of selecting the correct month.